# How to map PersistentVector of PersistentHashMaps in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I have a PersistentVector of PersistentHashMaps:

```
[
  {:url http://www.url.com, id: some_id ...},
  {:url http://www.url.com, id: some_id ...},
  {:url http://www.url.com, id: some_id ...},
]
```

What I need here to have a collection of all `id`s, so I need to map over a vector and from each map select `id` value.

I do:

```
(map #(get % :id) (all-users))
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Typically in Clojure we just talk about Vectors and Maps and don't mention the underlying Classes because there are several kinds of persistent vectors and maps for efficiency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keywords can be used as functions.

```
(map :id (all-users))
```

If you are on Clojure 1.7 and don't need laziness, e. g.  want to realize they entire collection as a vector you can use the map transducer:

```
(into [] (map :id) (all-users))
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you know that you need the lazy behavior of map, I would always suggest using `mapv`:

```
(def all-users [ {:id 111 ...} 
                 {:id 222 ...}
                 ... ] )
(mapv :id all-users)
```

The difference is that `mapv` is always evaluated immediately, and it stuffs the results in to a vector for easy access. Lazy sequences are great for things that are either very large or very slow, but they introduces an added layer of timing uncertainty that is unneeded by 99% of use cases.

Comment: Your post reads as "use `mapv` as a default which is bad advice IMO. Thus I downvote it. Also: random access, not easy access; per step overhead, not timing. 99% stat is way off, quite contrary `mapv` isn't useful 99% of the time: Large Clojure programs consist of many transformation steps and lazy sequences are the idiomaitc building block precisely because you do not want to allocate new vectors between steps, especially when you don't know how the result will be processed by your functions users. Transducers are a general solution to the problem you describe, `mapv` never has been one.